# Why moc error is caused by not a pure method?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, pure-virtual, moc

I'm writing some project using Qt Creator.

I've created an interface for different graph implementations, which are derived from it. I'm adding methods to this *Graph.h* file time to time, thus I forgot to mark one method *pure* once. This lead to **"Undefined reference to 'vtable for Graph'"** error, which I've read a lot about and have some notion about MOC files. But not an option helped me to solve my problem, so I've decided to copy an old version of my project (which worked just fine) and compare it with the current one. By doing this I've noticed, that one of the functions in *Graph.h* wasn't marked *pure*.

So my question is: **Why not marking a method as pure caused a moc error?**

Here's some code:

Interface Graph.h

```
class Graph {
public:
    Graph() = default;
    virtual ~Graph() = default;

    /* some other stuff here */

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::vector<int> topologicalSort() const; //this function was forgotten to be marked pure

};
```

MGraph.h

```
#include "Graph.h"

class MGraph : Graph
{
private:
    /* some stuff here */

public:
    MGraph();
    explicit MGraph(int nodes, int edges = 0, bool directed = false, bool weighted = false);
    explicit MGraph(const LGraph& lGraph);
    ~MGraph();

    /* some stuff here */

    [[nodiscard]] std::vector<int> topologicalSort() const override;

};
```

**"Undefined reference to 'vtable for Graph'"** error was directed to constructor and destructor of Graph.

Comment: As the virtual function was not defined the compiler did not create vtable because it does not have the address of the function definition.

Comment: I would think this a general C++/linker error and had nothing to do with moc or Qt even. (The class is not a QObject either)